# Tem como definir o tipo das variáveis nos parâmetros de um método?

Tags: php

Assim como é feito em varias linguagens de programação, como Java, C# e muitas outras, tem como definir em PHP o tipo de variável que queremos que seja inicializada nos parâmetros de um método?

**O código abaixo é um exemplo do que eu estou falando, só que em Java**

```
//Nesse método, foi especificado que a variável "i" deverá ser do tipo int
public void executar(int i) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem como definir se o tipo for array ou objeto. No PHP 7 essa funcionalidade foi estendida, e hoje é possível utilizar isso com int, float e afins. Para utilizar essa funcionalidade é bem simples. Exemplo:

```
public function teste(int $a, string $b)
{
}
```

Também é possível especificar o tipo de retorno (PHP7), para isso basta fazer :

```
public function sum(int $a, int $b) : int 
{
}
```

Comment: Muito bom saber, agora virei fã do PHP 7